# How to transfer Either.Right to Either.Left?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, ramda.js, ramda-fantasy

```
db.findUser(id).then(R.pipe(
  R.ifElse(firstTestHere, Either.Right, () => Either.Left(err)),
  R.map(R.ifElse(secondTestHere, obj => obj, () => Either.Left(err))),
  console.log
))
```

If the first test doesn't pass, it will return Either.Left, and the second one won't be called. It will out put:

`_Right {value: user}`

But if the first one passed but the second one doesn't, it will become:

`_Right {value: _Left {value: err}}`

I want it to output _Left {value: err} only, how to fix the code or is there any way to transfer the Right to the Left?

Comment: Where is your `err` parameter coming from?

Comment: It is just I declare somewhere else like: () => new Error('some err msg here')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've noticed there is that `map` is unable to "flatten" the two `Either` instances together. To do that, you will want to use [`chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) instead.

```
db.findUser(id).then(R.pipe(
  R.ifElse(firstTestHere, Either.Right, () => Either.Left(err)),
  R.chain(R.ifElse(secondTestHere, Either.Right, () => Either.Left(err))),
  console.log
))
```

This pattern of composing series of calls to chain together can also be achieved with [`composeK`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#composeK)/[`pipeK`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeK), where each function that is to be composed must take the form `Monad m => a -> m b`, i.e. a function that produces some monad (such as `Either`) from a given value.

Using `R.pipeK`, your example could be modified to something like:

```
// helper function to wrap up the `ifElse` logic
const assertThat = (predicate, error) =>
  R.ifElse(predicate, Either.Right, _ => Either.Left(error))

const result = db.findUser(id).then(R.pipeK(
  assertThat(firstTestHere, err),
  assertThat(secondTestHere, err)
));
```